# Possible Bug - Business Unit Subscriber Status Data View has no records?

Tags: dataextensions, sql, automationstudio

The BusinessUnitUnsubscribes Data View which is meant to contain the unsubscribe reason has no records.

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS count
FROM
  [_BusinessUnitUnsubscribes] AS bu
```

Returns 0.

Is this data view meant to be empty? Am i querying it incorrectly? Is there an alternative way of getting unsubscribe reason?

In particular I am looking for the RMM and List-Unsubscribe reasons like I would from the Tracking Extract but looking to Query via the Data View. I know that alternatively I could export the tracking extract and import it into a DE for querying but that defeats the purpose of the Data View. Can anyone please confirm that this Data View is currently working as expected or also broken? Thanks.

Comment: It all depends on how you're handling unsubscribes in your emails and your business unit's unsubscribe scope.  Perhaps you can clarify.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not [logging unsubscribe events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/unsubscribing_and_logging_an_unsubevent_with_a_logunsubevent_execute_call.html) like a stock preference center would, then you should expect this data view to be empty.
Toggling the status in the Subscriber object will not trigger the unsubscribe in tracking or the data views.

[Here's an example](https://sprignaturemoves.com/one-click-unsubscribe-with-ampscript/) of a custom one-click unsubscribe page that will result in the proper recording of the event.

I've written about some nuances with the `_BusinessUnitUnsubsribes` [here](https://sprignaturemoves.com/determining-business-unit-subscriber-status/).

Comment: Just trying to get the `Unsubscribe Reason` so i can add it to my `_Unsubscribes` Data View SQL Export. There is drastic differences between the Tracking Extract and the Data View SQL Export for Unsubscribes in particular to the point where I wonder if it's a bug. The Data View contain both 1) `RMM unsubs` and 2) `List-Unsub` whereas the Tracking Extract only contains the `RMM unsubs` but also the Reason. In the end, all I want is my unsubs in one export with the reason.